# KeyBinding for getting text from JTextField

Tags: java, input, key-bindings

I have a `JTextField` that will hold the user's input before they submit it (like a console `Scanner` object if you will). My main class has a method for getting input from the user. With a `Scanner` object this was easy to do: `scannerObject.nextLine()`. With this `JTextField`, I decided to use Key Bindings to determine when the Enter key was pressed in order to "submit" the contents of the `JTextField`. I set up the Key Bindings no problem, but I can't figure out how to get the main program to wait until the Enter key is pressed to look for the text. If I use a loop, the program gets stuck and cannot register the key press.

Here is a method that tries to get the input from the `JTextField`:

```
public static String getStrInput() {
    // Request input
    display.print(">> ");
    needInput = true;
    nextInput = "";

    // Wait until a string is input from the text field
    while (nextInput.isEmpty());    // Wait

    needInput = false;

    return nextInput;
}
```

And here is the Event Handler for when the Enter key is pressed in my Key Binding class:

```
private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * Makes Java happy.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* -- Constructor -- */
    public SubmitAction() {
    }

    /* -- Method -- */

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (Game.needInput())
            Game.submitTextField();
    }
}
```

Note: All the `submitTextField()` method does is call the `textField.getText()` method and set the `nextInput` field (see my first method) to the returned String.

What is supposed to happen is the request for input should be registered (this is the `needInput = true` line), and the Key Binding class should then submit the text field when the Enter key is pressed (since the `Game.needInput()` condition now returns true). However, in my `getStrInput()` method, the program gets stuck in the `while (nextInput.isEmpty());` loop. I figured that this would happen, but I have no clue how to get the main program to wait until the Key Binding's event handler has the text field submit its contents.

If this makes no sense at all or I need to reveal more code, I will happily elaborate. I've spent all day working on this little problem just to find frustration.

Comment: Game shouldn't be actively waiting for some other action listener to tell it there's input; Game should set its own action listener and passively wait for that listener to be called.

Comment: @KevinAnderson That sounds like a good idea. Could you provide some insight on how to do that? I'm very inexperienced with event handlers and action listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With this JTextField, I decided to use Key Bindings to determine when the Enter key was pressed in order to "submit" the contents of the JTextField.

Actually you should just be adding an ActionListener to the text field. The ActionListener will be invoked when the Enter key is pressed.

If you want to prompt and wait for text to be entered, then you should be using a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think of the `JOptionPane`. That will likely be enough for this simple program I'm making. In the future though, how would you recommend waiting for text to be entered?

Comment: `In the future though, how would you recommend waiting for text to be entered?` - You are making it too complicate. This is the proper solution. a JOptionPane is designed for this purpose.

Comment: @elektrikpulse61, glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Okay. I guess that makes sense, but I would still like to know how to wait for text to be entered. I think it makes the program look nicer with its own built-in input box as opposed to a window popping up, but I do appreciate your response. I'll be sure to check that arrow.

Comment: @elektrikpulse61, `I think it makes the program look nicer with its own built-in input box as opposed to a window popping up` - that is not the way GUI's work. Think of applications that have a login, so you need to enter a userid/password. The user indicates they are finished entering data by clicking on a button. You don't need a "popup" for this, but you do need a button. Then you add an ActionListener to the button (and the text field as I already stated). Then when the user is finished they click the button and your process continues. This is how event driven processing is done.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean. Thanks for your help. I used a combination of what I learned here with some of my own trial-and error to get something that works well for what I need. Thanks again.